# Create a page that self executes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys, I'm trying to create a web app similar to a web crawler on my site. I have just about all the code done to do the crawling, but I still need to physically go to the web page to activate the code. Is there any way I could have my ASP.NET code execute automatically once every day on the server? (I'm using godaddy if that makes any difference)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a "page," you want a scheduled console app or a Windows service.  A page, by design, is a request-able server resource.  (Look into RESTful design.)  It's meant to be invoked by a request from a client, perhaps perform some server-side logic, and return a response to that client.  End of story.

Your site could spawn off a thread of some sort on the start of the application, I suppose.  Seems like a bit of a hack to me, though.  But if that's the only option you have with your hosting provider then that may indeed be the way to go.  (Though you'd still have to call the page at least once to start it.)  But, ideally, you'd want an on-going process to be handled by an application or Windows service outside of the site itself.

(If you do go with a thread that's spawned at application startup, just be aware of the various things that can cause an application to re-start.  Once it's up, that doesn't mean it's going to stay up.  Any change to the config file, changes to pages or code in certain project types, IIS wants to free up resources and feels like restarting the pool, etc.)

Comment: All the inside-ASP.NET approaches would definitely be "hackish". You can do a recurring cache callback or something that is triggered in OnRequest but only executes daily (possibly using app state or cache to store a last-execution timestamp for comparison). Neither would be 100 percent reliable on a single server, let alone servers that may recycle their app pool with any sort of regularity. Neither scale well to multiple servers (no clue what GoDaddy has hosting on by default).

Comment: @patridge: Exactly.  In a world of separating concerns, this is a concern that needs to be separated from the web application.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to not use a webpage, but to create a class with a method that does what you need, and to call that from the Application_OnStart event in the global.asax file. The code might be accessed more than once per day however. But you could, if you are using a database, persist a configuration value to say when the last day the process was run. And then only run if the current day is not equal to the last ran date.

Comment: surely Application_OnStartup won't run until the first page is called anyway?

Comment: @Chris Simpson it won't run until a request is made and the application starts. This could cause a delay for the first visitor. This also sounds like a routine that would be good to put in a thread, and kick it off and just let it finish whenever. Then users can still use the site, and the new information retrieved by the crawler will be available eventually. Depending on how much traffic the site gets, Application_OnStart could happen several times a day, so that would need to be accommodated.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling execution of a web page for your purposes is not ideal, but:

If you are willing to have your browser open at all times, you can put this in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--    
  var timer = setInterval("autoRefresh()", 1000 * 60 * 1440);
  function autoRefresh(){self.location.reload(true);}
//--> 
</script>
```

Or, you can create a cron job on a *nix server to call your page daily:

```
* 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://www.domain.com/page
```